# Python File handling: standard input and output

Tags: file, python-2.7, readline, readfile

```
import sys 

fileobject=open('file.txt','w')   
fileobject.write(sys.stdin.readline())
Cat
```

In the above code, shouldn't cat be in file after execution? However, when I run it, I find file empty. If my code is wrong, can someone explain how `sys.stdin.read()` and `sys.stdout.write()` work and their uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the file

```
import sys 

fileobject = open('file.txt', 'w')   
fileobject.write(sys.stdin.readline())
Cat
fileobject.close()
```

If you want to see the updated file content before closing the file or exiting the program you can use flush():

```
fileobject.flush()
```

Check this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555402/understanding-stdin-stdout-stderr%20question) for standard input/output